# Как можно расположить текст по середине кривой?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

```html
<svg width="900" height="200" viewBox="0 0 900 200" style='border: 1px solid black' >
  <defs>
<path id="path10"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 6.3499999,18.39375 C 94.232184,85.363034 149.89644,17.864573 150.54791,17.070833 v 0"
        
        />
</defs>

<text x='100' y='100' font-size="24" text-anchor="middle" fill="blue">
   <textPath xlink:href="#path10" startOffset="10%" >
          Текст на кривой
   </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

```html
<style>
#path10 {
fill:none;
stroke:teal;
stroke-width:3;
}
.txt1 {
fill:#026282;
font-size:25px;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="600" height="500" viewBox="0 0 600 500" style="border:1px solid gray" >  

<path id="path10" d="M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200"/>
<text class="txt1">
      <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="0%" xlink:href="#path10">
     <tspan dy="-10">Текст на кривой линии</tspan>
   </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky  почти по горизонтали и вертикали и чтобы полностью надпись можно было бы прочитать

Comment: @MaximLensky я path делал в inkscape; и по вертикали по середине;  я ушел буду не скоро :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<textPath>` используется для привязки текста к линии.
Атрибут: [startOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/startOffset) используется для позиционирования начального символа относительно начала линии.

- При `startOffset="0"` первый символ слова будет совпадать с началом
  линии

```html
<style>
#path10 {
fill:none;
stroke:teal;
stroke-width:3;
}
.txt1 {
fill:#026282;
font-size:25px;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="border:1px solid gray" >  

<path id="path10" d="M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200"/>
<text class="txt1">
      <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="0%" xlink:href="#path10">
     <tspan dy="-10">Текст на кривой линии</tspan>
   </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

- При `startOffset="50%"` первый символ слова будет совпадать с серединой
  линии

```html
<style>
#path10 {
fill:none;
stroke:teal;
stroke-width:3;
}
.txt1 {
fill:#026282;
font-size:25px;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="border:1px solid gray" >  

<path id="path10" d="M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200"/>
<text class="txt1">
      <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#path10">
     <tspan dy="-10">Текст на кривой линии</tspan>
   </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

`text-anchor:middle;` позиционирует фразу по середине относительно заданной точки.
Этой заданной точкой является середина кривой, заданная атрибутом `startOffset="50%"`

Таким образом используя эти два атрибута вместе получаем:
**Фраза расположена симметрично по своей длине относительно середины кривой**

параметр `dy="-10"` служит для обеспечения зазора между кривой и текстом

```html
<style>
#path10 {
fill:none;
stroke:teal;
stroke-width:3;
}
.txt1 {
fill:#026282;
font-size:25px;
text-anchor:middle;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 400" style="border:1px solid gray" >  

<path id="path10" d="M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200"/>
<text class="txt1">
      <textPath
       id="result"
       method="align"
       spacing="auto"
       startOffset="50%"
       xlink:href="#path10">
     <tspan dy="-10">Текст на кривой линии</tspan>
   </textPath>
</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Примеры анимации с использованием startOffset

**1. Движение цепочки вдоль направляющей**

Вместо букв использованы символы [юникода](https://unicode-table.com/ru/1D11/), что позволило анимировать несколько объектов сразу, по сравнению с командой анимации `animateMotion`, где допустимо анимировать сразу только один объект.

`&#7441;` ᴑ - Латинская маленькая буква на боку, что делает её похожей на звено цепи.
  `&#45;` - И перемычка между звеньями цепи.

Движение цепи туда-обратно реализует анимация изменения `startOffset`

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="100 100 400 300">

 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>

<text font-size="36"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="grey" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
<tspan dx="0" > &#7441; </tspan> <tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan>
<animate  dur="10s" repeatCount="2" attributeName="startOffset" values="1%;55%;1%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>    
   
</svg>
```

**2.  Анимация кривой Безье с текстом-ссылкой на ней**

В этом примере используется анимация атрибута `d` `path`формула которого,  реализует 
[квадратичную кривую Безье](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=914#comm_Quadratic)

*Наведите курсор на фразу*

```html
<style>
  svg {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/hawaii-beach.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  width:50%
  height:50%
  }
 </style>
  
 <svg   viewBox="0 0 600 500">
 
 
<defs> 
 <path id="Lsvg" d="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200" style="stroke:teal;fill-opacity:0.3;stroke-width:3;fill:none">
<animate begin="animLink.mouseover"  dur="10s" restart="whenNotActive"  attributeName="d" 
values="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,300 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200"/> 
</path>

</defs>
<text text-anchor="middle" font-size="25" fill="#026282">
      <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#Lsvg"><tspan dy="-20">So easy to do with SVG just  few lines</tspan></textPath>
<animate begin="animLink.mouseover"   dur="10s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="fill"
values="red;green;red;green;red"/>
</text>
<use xlink:href="#Lsvg" transform="translate(0 -10)"/>
   
  <rect id="animLink" x="100" y="150" width="400" height="60" fill="#E0E0E0" fill-opacity="0.01" stroke="none" />  

 </svg>
```

**3. Анимация текста по кругу**

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 400 450">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop stop-color="#406666" offset="0%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#fcfcfc" offset="50%"/>
      <stop stop-color="#507676" offset="100%"/>
      <animate attributeName="x2" begin="start.click" dur="10s" values="0;0.25;0.5;0.75;1" repeatCount="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
<path id="path1" d="M92 262.5L92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5
                    200,325 92,262.5 92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5 200,325 92,262.5" fill="none" stroke="none"/>
   </defs>
<rect x='0' y='0' width='400' height='450' fill='#DDDDDD' stroke='black'/>
<rect x="1" y="1" width="398" height="378"
        fill="white" stroke="#507676" stroke-width="1" />
<polygon id="pol1" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="#507676" stroke-width="1" 
            points="200,75  308,137.5 308,262.5
                    200,325 92,262.5 92,137.5" />
<text id="txt1" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="700" font-size="24">
<textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="1%" xlink:href="#path1">
<tspan dy="-10"> Весь очень длинный текст целиком вокруг шестиугольника</tspan>
<animate begin="start.click" dur="10s" repeatCount="1" attributeName="startOffset" values="4%;54%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>
<g id="start">
<rect  x="285" y="387" rx="10" width="90" height="35" style="fill:#507676;"/>
<text x='300' y='412' fill="white" font-size="25">Старт</text> 
</g>
  <path id="path2" transform="scale(1.25) translate(-40 -40)" d="M92 262.5L92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5
                    200,325 92,262.5 92,137.5 200,75 308,137.5 308,262.5 200,325 92,262.5" fill="none" stroke="#507676" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1"/> 
</svg>
```

**4. Ещё один пример анимации startOffset**

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 -10 120 120">

          <!-- Зелёеая окружность    -->
   <circle cx="55" cy="55" r="50" style="fill:none;stroke:#92D050;stroke-width:10" />
    <!-- Красный сегмент -->
     <circle  cx="55" cy="55" r="50" stroke="#C0504D" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="78.5 235.5" stroke-dashoffset="117.75" fill="none" />
          <!-- Path для текста -->
  <path id="top-sector" style="fill:none;stroke:none" d="M 9,50 A 46,46.5 0 0 1 100.5,50" /> 
 <text id="txt1" text-anchor="middle">
      <textPath xlink:href="#top-sector" startOffset="50%" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight:700;">Hello World 
      <!-- Анимация движения текста начинается после щелчка -->
       <animate
      begin="svg1.click"
   dur="4s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="50%;42%;50%;50%;58%;50%;50%"/>
   </textPath> 
         <!-- Анимация перерисовки текста начинается после щелчка    -->
    <animate
      attributeName="fill"
   to="yellow"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="0.2s"
   fill="freeze" /> 
     </text> 
 
 <text x="46%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14px" fill="dodgerblue"> Click me </text>

</svg>
```

Comment: первый код там  viewBox="100 100 400 300" это нужно для увеличенмя ?

Comment: @Leks 100 100  это смещения по горизонтали и вертикали. Сделал чтобы пример в сниппет попал, а то некоторым даже лень сниппет развернуть :)